# How to read a file that is stored locally on a network computer?

Tags: java

Im am using NetBeans to create a java web application. One of the modules I use needs to parse xml files which are stored locally on a computer in the network, but what is the best way to reach those files?

I stumbled across various threads on SO about this with several solutions (SFTP, FTP, NFS, HTTP) but I can't figure out wwhat is best suitable for my situation.

We have a network with all linux operated machines and I can reach the remote machine with ssh and therefore know the IP-address of it.

ps storing the files in a shared folder is not allowed for us :(

Comment: Ask your system admin what is allowed then. I guess he would know better than the SO community.

Answer (score 2):

First connect to the remote machine. I prefer Jsch for it. And the code to connect and trasfer file to local machine I have given below. to read and delete the file guess that should be easy work ! :)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   String username = "your username";
   String host = "192.*.*.*";
   String pass = "password";

   JSch jsch = null;
   Session session = null;
   Channel channel = null;
   ChannelSftp c = null;
   try {
       jsch = new JSch();
       System.out.println("Setting Up SFTP Connection...");
       session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
       session.setPassword(pass);
       System.out.println("SFTP Configration Complete..!");  
       java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
       config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
       session.setConfig(config);
       System.out.println("Attempting to Connect..!"); 
       session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
       session.connect();
       System.out.println("Session Connected."); 
       channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
       channel.connect();

       System.out.println("Channel Connected."); 
       c = (ChannelSftp) channel;
       System.out.println("Connection Established\n");
               } catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
       }



   try {

     String SourceFolderPath= "/hta1/home/pinDap75a/DestinationDemo/YOURFILE.XML";
     String Destiantion = "C:/Users/Documents/";

       System.out.println("Starting Downlaod...");
       c.get(SourceFolderPath, Destiantion);

       System.out.println("File Transfer Complete! \n");
   } 

   catch (Exception e) {    e.printStackTrace();    }

   c.disconnect();
   session.disconnect();
}}
```

Comment: If ur very sure about reading the file directly use Filereader or BufferedReader, pass the file path as arg and read line by line. First use the above code and connect. Later will add the code to read it directly

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read file using FTP or SFTP accordingly as allowed. Following are the step you should do, their may be more.

- Import some useful libraries.
- Connect to server using FTP/SFTP.
- Download your required file.
- Read your file.
- Delete the file. (recommended)

see example [FTP](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example) / [SFTP](http://www.example-code.com/java/sftp_downloadByName.asp)